# Unmet peer dependencies installing Eslint and plugins

Tags: node.js, eslint

EDIT2: Now it works. Had to remove all local eslint packages. All is good!

EDIT: Okay, after installing the specific version it was complaining about(^1.16.0) it now works in command line again. But that did sadly not help for within Sublime. Are there any settings that might be wrong here?

I had this working before but after installing the same packages again by mistake, it broke. Ultimately I'm trying to get ESLINT to work with Sublime. And I think everything in Sublime is correct since I haven't changed anything there. It's just that Eslint doesn't work anymore which 'eslint app.jsx' etc shows (see below).

I get this error of unmet peer dependencies on eslint-plugin-import.

```
aa:myResolutions Andreas$ sudo npm install -g eslint eslint-plugin-import

Password:

/usr/local/bin/eslint -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js

/usr/local/lib

├── eslint@3.7.1 

└── eslint-plugin-import@2.0.0 


aa:myResolutions Andreas$ sudo npm install -g eslint eslint-plugin-import 
eslint-config-airbnb eslint-plugin-react eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y

/usr/local/bin/eslint -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js

/usr/local/lib

├── eslint@3.7.1 

├─┬ eslint-config-airbnb@12.0.0 

│ └── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY eslint-plugin-import@^1.16.0

├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY eslint-plugin-import@2.0.0

├── eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@2.2.2 

└── eslint-plugin-react@6.3.0 


npm WARN eslint-config-airbnb@12.0.0 requires a peer of eslint-plugin-
import@^1.16.0 but none was installed.

npm WARN eslint-config-airbnb-base@8.0.0 requires a peer of eslint-plugin-
import@^1.16.0 but none was installed.

aa:myResolutions Andreas$ eslint App.jsx 


Oops! Something went wrong! :(


ESLint couldn't find the plugin "eslint-plugin-import". This can happen for a 
couple different reasons:


1. If ESLint is installed globally, then make sure eslint-plugin-import is 
also installed globally. A globally-installed ESLint cannot find a locally-
installed plugin.


2. If ESLint is installed locally, then it's likely that the plugin isn't 
installed correctly. Try reinstalling by running the following:

npm i eslint-plugin-import@latest --save-dev
```

I don't get it. I first installed it. But then it's not installed anymore? Or at least it can't be found by some other packages?

Been scratching my head on this for over a day now. All plugins are installed globally so that shouldn't be the issue, and it was like that before it broke as well. And I've completely reinstalled node/npm but nothing seems to help.

Anyone have any idea as how to solve this?

Answer (score 6):

Notice that on the [AirBnB config package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb), they state some additional information before installing.

First remove all the packages that were installed, which should be the following:

```
npm uninstall eslint-plugin-react eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y eslint-plugin-import
```

Next, terminal run:

```
export PKG=eslint-config-airbnb;
npm info "$PKG" peerDependencies --json | command sed 's/[\{\},]//g ; s/: /@/g' | xargs npm install --save-dev "$PKG"
```

This will produce the correct dependencies eg:

```
npm install --save-dev eslint-config-airbnb eslint@^#.#.# eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@^#.#.# eslint-plugin-import@^#.#.# eslint-plugin-react@^#.#.#
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42288376/how-to-install-eslint-config-airbnb-properly-unmet-peer-dependency/44813949#44813949):

```
npm i -g eslint-config-airbnb-standard
eslint -v
```

Answer (score 0):

After uninstalling `eslint-plugin-import`, `eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y`, `eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y`, and `eslint-plugin-react`, you can install `eslint-config-airbnb` along with its peer dependencies:

For npm 5+:

```
npx install-peerdeps --dev eslint-config-airbnb
```

For npm < 5:

```
(
  export PKG=eslint-config-airbnb;
  npm info "$PKG@latest" peerDependencies --json | command sed 's/[\{\},]//g ; s/: /@/g' | xargs npm install --save-dev "$PKG@latest"
)
```

Comment: For npm < 5, here's a one-liner: `npm info "eslint-config-airbnb@latest" peerDependencies --json | command sed 's/[\{\},]//g ; s/: /@/g' | xargs npm install --save-dev "eslint-config-airbnb@latest";`