# How to install eslint-config-airbnb properly ? `UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY`

Tags: javascript, npm, eslint

```
➜  beslint git:(master) ✗ eslint -v
    v3.15.0
➜  beslint git:(master) ✗ npm install -g eslint-config-airbnb eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y eslint-plugin-import eslint-plugin-react

/Users/next/.nvm/versions/node/v7.5.0/lib
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY eslint@^3.15.0
├─┬ eslint-config-airbnb@14.1.0
│ └── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY eslint@^3.15.0
├── eslint-plugin-import@2.2.0
├── eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@4.0.0
└── eslint-plugin-react@6.10.0

npm WARN eslint-config-airbnb@14.1.0 requires a peer of eslint@^3.15.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN eslint-config-airbnb-base@11.1.0 requires a peer of eslint@^3.15.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-import@2.2.0 requires a peer of eslint@2.x - 3.x but none was installed.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@4.0.0 requires a peer of eslint@^2.10.2 || 3.x but none was installed.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-react@6.10.0 requires a peer of eslint@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 but none was installed.
➜  beslint git:(master) ✗
```

- I tired to install globally
- I use nvm to install `node 7.5.0`, and installed eslint globally.
- when I try to install `eslint-config-airbnb` globally.
- It said `UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY`

Comment: Have you tried... *installing* the dependency?

Comment: Does the WARN shows what I have to install exactly the peer ? I thought I already installed the eslint globally that will MEET the requirements. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 5):

You can install `eslint-config-airbnb-bundle`. This is an **unaltered** *Airbnb style guide config* bundled with ESLint in a single package to solve some inconvenience with the installation (like unmet peer dependency warnings). You can install it globally as well:

```
npm i -g eslint-config-airbnb-bundle
```

Airbnb only: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb-bundle

Airbnb + Standard: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb-standard

Answer (score 3):

I faced similar issue but found a solution to this issue. I thought its worth sharing.

To install the correct versions of each package related eslint config , 
You can run following command :

```
npm info "eslint-config-airbnb@latest" peerDependencies
```

You can get exact peer dependency which are listed by running above command:

e.g about outputs ( as of answer's date ) will produce following :

```
{ eslint: '^3.19.0 || ^4.3.0',
  'eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y': '^5.1.1',
  'eslint-plugin-import': '^2.7.0',
  'eslint-plugin-react': '^7.1.0' 
}
```

From above output you can exact idea about what dependencies to install for current ( latest build) .

If you want to install all dependencies in one go ( for Linux/OSX users only)
Use below command :

```
(
  export PKG=eslint-config-airbnb;
  npm info "$PKG@latest" peerDependencies --json | command sed 's/[\{\},]//g ; s/: /@/g' | xargs npm install --save-dev "$PKG@latest"
)
```

More details [here](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/packages/eslint-config-airbnb).

Answer (score 3):

From https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb

```
npx install-peerdeps --dev eslint-config-airbnb
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you should install everything global. Try this:

`npm install --save-dev eslint eslint-config-airbnb eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y eslint-plugin-import eslint-plugin-react`

Answer (score -1):

Removing node modules (`rm -rf node_modules/`) and re-running `npm install` worked for me!!